# What decides which production the parser tries?

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to build a parser for a desk calculator and am using the following bison code for it.

```
%union{
    float f;
    char c;
    // int 
}

%token <f> NUM
%token <c> ID
%type <f> S E T F G

%%

C   :   S ';'
    |   C S ';'
    ;

S   :   ID '=' E    {fprintf(debug,"13\n");printf("%c has been assigned the value %f.",$1,$3);symbolTable[$1]=$3;}
    |   E           {fprintf(debug,"12\n");result = $$;}
    ;

E   :   E '+' T     {fprintf(debug,"11\n");$$ = $1+$3;}
    |   E '-' T     {fprintf(debug,"10\n");$$ = $1-$3;}
    |   T           {fprintf(debug,"9\n");$$ = $1;}
    ;

T   :   T '*' F     {fprintf(debug,"7\n");$$ = $1*$3;}
    |   T '/' F     {fprintf(debug,"6\n");$$ = $1/$3;}
    |   F           {fprintf(debug,"5\n");$$ = $1;}
    ; 

F   :   G '@' F     {fprintf(debug,"4\n");$$ = pow($1,$3);}
    |   G           {fprintf(debug,"3\n");$$ = $1;}
    ;

G   :   '(' E ')'   {fprintf(debug,"2\n");$$ = $2;}
    |   NUM         {fprintf(debug,"1\n");$$ = $1;}
    |   ID          {fprintf(debug,"0\n");$$ = symbolTable[$1];}
    ;

%%
```

My LEX rules are

```
digit   [0-9]
num     {digit}+
alpha   [A-Za-z]
id      {alpha}({alpha}|{digit})*
white   [\ \t]

%%
let     {printf("let");return LET;}
{num}   {yylval.f = atoi(yytext);return NUM;}
{alpha} {yylval.c = yytext[0];return ID;}
[+\-\*/@\(\)]   {return yytext[0];}
.       {}
%%
```

The input I gave is `a=2+3`
When the lexer returns an `ID`(for `'a'`), the parser is going for the production with `fprintf(debug,"0\n")`. But I want it to go for the production `fprintf(debug,"13\n")`.

So, I am wondering what made my parser go for a reduction on production 0, instead of shifting `=` to stack, and how do I control it?

Comment: OT: That grammar seems wrong to me. If `ID` can only be produced in `E`, then `3+a` cannot be parsed. `NUM` is a `G`, so `3*3` is fine. `ID` is an `E`, so `a+3` is also fine. But `T` cannot produce `ID`, so `a+3` is impossible. (And so is `a*b`, etc.). You probably wanted `G: ID`, not `E: ID`.

Comment: @rici Thank you for pointing that out. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: As you aren't building a compiler, [tag:compiler-construction] does not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the problem is I am not identifying `=` as a token here, in my LEX.

As silly as it sounds, it points out a very important concept of yacc/Bison. The question of whether to shift or reduce is answered by checking the next symbol, also called the lookahead. In this case, the lookahead was `NUM`(for `2`) and not `=`, because of my faulty LEX code. Since there is no production involving `ID` followed by `NUM`, it is going for a reduction to `G`.

And about how I figured it out, it turns out bison has a built-in [trace feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Enabling-Traces). It lays out neatly like a diary entry, whatever it does while parsing. each and every step is written down.

To enable it,

Run `bison` with `-Dparse.trace` option.

`bison calc.y -d -Dparse.trace`

In the main function of parser grab the extern yydebug and set it to non-zero value.

```
int main(){
   extern int yydebug;
   yydebug = 1;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected. An important take-away here: don't try to insert your own debugging printf's into a bison parser; you are bound to miss some important piece of data. Instead, use bison's built-in [trace facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing). This would have immediately shown you the problem. (Follow the instructions carefully. You need to do two things: (1) process the bison grammar with the `-t`  option so that debugging code is generated, and (2) set the global `yydebug` to a non-zero value so that traces are actually printed.)

Comment: @rici Yes. That is exactly how I figured it out. I'll edit my answer to include that as well. Thanks for the suggestion about debugging printf's, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually specified is a translation grammar, given by the following:
C → S ';' 14 | C S ';' 8
S → ID '=' E 13 | E 12
E → E '+' T 11 | E '-' T 10 | T 9
T → T '*' F 7 | T "/" F 6 | F 5
F → G '@' F 4 | G 3
G → '(' E ')' 2 | NUM 1 | ID 0
with top-level/start configuration C. (For completeness, I added in 8 and 14).

There is only one word generated from C, by this translation grammar, containing ID '=' NUM '+' NUM as the subword of input tokens, and that is ID ('a') '=' NUM('2') 1 3 5 9 '+' NUM('3') 1 3 5 11 13 ';' 14, which is equal to the input-output pair (ID '=' NUM '+' NUM ';', 1 3 5 9 1 3 5 11 13 14). So, the sequence 1 3 5 9 1 3 5 11 13 14 is the one and only translation. Provided the grammar is LALR(1), then this translation will be produced, as a result; and the grammar is LALR(1).

If you're not getting this result, then that can only mean that you implemented wrong whatever you left out of your description: i.e. the lexer ... or that your grammar processor has a bug or your machine has a failure.

And, no; actually what you did is the better way to see what's going on - just stick in a single printf statement to the right hand side of each rule and run it that way to see what translation sequences are produced. The "trace" facility in the parser generator is superfluous for that very reason ... at least the way it is usually implemented (more on that below). In addition, you can get a direct view of everything with the -v option, which produces the LR(0) tables with LALR(1) annotations.

The kind of built-in testing facility that would actually be more helpful - especially for examples like this - is just what I described: one that echoes the inputs interleaved with the output actions. So, when you run it on "a = 2 + 3 ;", it would give you ID('a') '=' NUM('2') 1 3 5 9 '+' NUM('3') 1 3 5 11 13 ';' 14 with echo turned on, and just 1 3 5 9 1 3 5 11 13 14 with echo turned off. That would actually be more useful to have as a built-in capability, instead of the trace mode you normally see in implementations of yacc.

The POSIX specification actually leaves open the issue of how "YYDEBUG", "yydebug" and "-t" are to be implemented in a compliant implementation of yacc, to make room for alternative approaches like this.